# Pandas Pivot_table with different dtype values

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have a particularly strange behavior from pivot_table (or at least I think it is...)

I have got a `dataframe` extracted from database with dates that I use with pivot table to do some basics stats:

```
pd.pivot_table(df,values["Diff_DGach_Dcent","Diff_DepCh_BoxPlt","Attente_totale"],
                    index=['id_chantier',"date_bl"], aggfunc=np.sum,fill_value=0)
```

I can pivot table on these fields but if I also add the fied "Cpt" to the values (it's a simple int field with 1 in it) to count how many lines are grouped by the pivot table , it'll only display the Cpt field but no more the timedelta ones...

Is it impossible to do the pivot table on different dtype ?

EDIT : 
Sample of Data to be processed

```
Diff_DGach_Dcent    Diff_DepCh_BoxPlt   Attente_totale  Cpt
    00:21:00    00:45:00    01:23:00    1
    00:26:00    00:18:00    02:16:00    1
    00:15:00    00:18:00    01:25:00    1
    00:25:00    00:18:00    01:25:00    1
    00:26:00    00:10:00    01:20:00    1
    00:20:00    00:14:00    01:38:00    1
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set the `columns` parameter to specify the group that you want the `values` to be grouped on.

Do you have sample data?

Comment: Hi , thanks for looking at my problem :) I've added some sample data : it's all timedelta64[ns] except for the Cpt which is int and always egal to 1